# Custom RPC Kerberos authentication working on Samba but dont Windows

Tags: windows, samba, kerberos, rpc

I have implemented an RPC client in C# which uses GSS/SPNEGO authentication. I am trying to connect to the standard/Active Directory services (DRSAPI, SAMR etc...) on the server. The authentication works fine except when using Kerberos authentication and I've been struggling for 1 week now trying to troubleshoot the error. The use cases are the following:

Samba NTLM => OK

Samba Kerberos => OK

Windows NTLM => OK

Windows (2012, 2016) Kerberos => KO

When trying Kerberos, the authentication to the KDC seems to work just fine, the ticket is obtained, but when trying to connect to the RPC service, the server respond with a [nca_s_fault_sec_pkg_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwOD4.png) (again, only on Windows 2012) and I can't find what is rubbing Windows the wrong way. I am not an expert in Kerberos and there doesn't seem to be any entry in the event viewer. I compared Wireshark traces with a working and non working authentication and I can't see any differences.

Can someone please help me identify what the error is? Let me know if you need more information, I can provide Network traces and logs (samba, app, windows)

**Edit**: [Here is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/25zpz2mw1dt70znv9vni0/Kerberos_Auth.zip?rlkey=64qcaoinw3syufo9e76gacm3g&dl=0) to working (Samba) and non working (Windows 2012) wireshark traces of the exact same code with only the user password and the address of the server (Samba = 192.168.1.49 and W2K12 = 192.168.1.151) as differences

Thanks